# wordpress category child_of variable instead of integer

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi im wondering is there a way to include a variable in the `child_of` parameter rather than an integer.
Im trying to retrieve the child categories based on the current category im on, but because there are 32 categories, it seems I have to write out 32 `elseif`s which seems wrong.

```
$current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$category = get_category($current_cat);
 if ( $category->parent == '16'  {
$cats=get_categories('child_of=16'); 
        }
```

But I dont want to have to repeat this over and over, 
Id rather do something like...

```
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $category = get_category($current_cat);
    $cat_parent = $category->parent;
    $cats = get_categories('child_of=$cat_parent);
```

Is it this possible? (ps im still learning so I may have missed something simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
$current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$category = get_category($current_cat);
$cat_parent = $category->parent;

//adding the variable
$cats = get_categories('child_of='.$cat_parent);
```